# SQL Query to calculate inventory on the first of each month over a date range

Tags: sql-server

SQL Server 2012-2017. Can this be done with a CTE? Trying to avoid using a cursor.

I have a report request to return the inventory for the first of each month between dateFrom and dateTo, excluding the inventory on the dateFrom and dateTo.

Inventory is tracked by status history for each item.  Each status history is coded as either in-inventory or out-of-inventory.

There could be many status history entries with an in-inventory status to track process steps.  There will be another status history entry when the item is shipped, broken, lost, etc, and those are coded as out-of-inventory.

For reporting, an item is in inventory if the most recent status in status history before the reporting date is one that we code as in-inventory.

```
DECLARE @dateFrom dateTime, @dateTo dateTime

SET @dateFrom = '2-Nov-2017'
SET @dateTo = '20-Feb-2018 23:59:59.9'

--this proves out the dates are calculating correctly
;WITH cteDateTest AS 
(
    SELECT 
        1 roundCount,
        DATEADD(M, DATEDIFF(M, 0, @dateFrom), 31) invDate --returns first of the month following dateFrom

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        roundCount + 1,
        DATEADD(M, 1, invDate) --this one would go into the row_number join
    FROM 
        cteDateTest
    WHERE 
        DATEADD(M, 1, invDate) < @DateTo 
)
SELECT * FROM cteDateTest
```

I've simplified the tables, using temp tables to be explicit that these are NOT the issue but created for ease in others understanding the problem.

```
CREATE TABLE #tempItems 
(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    itemDesc NVARCHAR (15) NULL,
    isActive BIT
)

INSERT INTO #tempItems (id, itemDesc, isActive)
SELECT 1, 'widget 1',1 UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'toy 2',1  UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'something 3',1  UNION ALL 
SELECT 4, 'prize 4',1  

CREATE TABLE #tempStatusHistory 
(
    historyID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    itemId INT,
    itemStatus NVARCHAR (25) NULL,
    statusDate DATETIME,
    statusIsInInventory BIT,
)

INSERT INTO #tempStatusHistory (historyID, itemId, itemStatus, statusDate, statusIsInInventory)
SELECT 1, 1, 'in receiving', '2017-10-10',1 UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 1, 'in test', '2017-10-11',1 UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 1, 'on shelves', '2017-10-31',1 UNION ALL 
SELECT 4, 2, 'in receiving', '2017-11-15',1 UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 2, 'in test', '2017-11-16',1 UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 2, 'on shelves', '2017-12-17',1 UNION ALL 
SELECT 7, 2, 'sold', '2017-12-24',0 UNION ALL
SELECT 8, 3, 'in test', '2017-11-18',1 UNION ALL
SELECT 9, 3, 'in repair', '2017-12-19',1 UNION 
SELECT 10, 3, 'returned to vendor', '2018-02-03',0 UNION ALL
SELECT 11, 4, 'in receiving', '2018-01-20',1 UNION ALL
SELECT 12, 4, 'on shelves', '2018-01-21',1 UNION ALL
SELECT 13, 4, 'sold', '2018-03-20',0 

--select * from #tempStatusHistory

/* Per above data:
widget 1 in inventory all these months.  Toy 2 in Dec 1 inventory. something 3 in Dec1, Jan 1, Feb 1 inventory, prize 4 in Feb 1 and Mar 1 inventory
Dec 1 inventory = 3 (widget 1, toy 2, something 3)
Jan 1 inventory = 2 (widget 1, something 3) 
Feb 1 inventory = 3 (widget 1, something 3, prize 4)
Mar 1 inventory = 2 (widget 1, prize 4)
*/

--Our normal way of getting inventory for @dateFrom
SELECT 
    SH.historyId historyId, I.itemDesc
FROM 
    #tempItems I
JOIN 
    (SELECT 
         ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY itemId ORDER BY statusDate DESC) AS [Index], 
         itemId, historyId, statusDate, statusIsInInventory
     FROM 
         #tempStatusHistory 
     WHERE 
         statusDate < @dateFrom) SH ON I.id = SH.itemId AND SH.[Index] = 1 
WHERE 
    SH.statusIsInInventory = 1

--trying to pull inventory for each month between @dateFrom and @dateTo (exclusive of the end dates)
--anchor part of cte
;WITH cteInv AS
(
    SELECT 
        1 roundCount,
        DATEADD(M, DATEDIFF(M, 0, @dateFrom), 31) invDate,
        DATEADD(M, 1, @dateFrom) staticDate,
        1 linkField,
        SH.historyId historyId,
        I.itemDesc
    FROM 
        #tempItems I
    JOIN 
        (SELECT 
             ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY itemId ORDER BY statusDate DESC) AS [Index], 
             itemId, historyId, statusDate, statusIsInInventory
         FROM 
             #tempStatusHistory 
         WHERE 
             statusDate < DATEADD(M, DATEDIFF(M, 0, @dateFrom), 31)) SH ON I.id = SH.itemId AND SH.[Index] = 1 
WHERE 
    SH.statusIsInInventory = 1
--recursive part
UNION ALL
SELECT
roundCount + 1
, DATEADD(M,1,invDate)
, DATEADD(M,1,@dateFrom) staticDate
, 1
, SH.historyId
, I.itemDesc
FROM #tempItems I
--invDate not happy below
JOIN (SELECT ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY itemId ORDER BY statusDate DESC) AS [Index], itemId, historyId, statusDate, statusIsInInventory
    FROM #tempStatusHistory WHERE statusDate < DATEADD(M,1,invDate)) SH ON I.id = SH.itemId AND SH.[Index] = 1
JOIN cteInv C ON I.isActive = C.linkField
WHERE DATEADD(M,1,invDate)< @dateTo AND SH.statusIsInInventory = 1
)
SELECT * from cteInv order by roundCount, invDate, itemDesc

drop table #tempItems
drop table #tempStatusHistory
```

the reference to invDate in the status history link shows as an error "invalid column name invDate".  I can't figure a way around this.  I also suspect an issue because if I replace invDate with @dateFrom in the same spot, I had expected the same inventory result for each month calculation, but it started multiplying itself.

Is cte a good solution for this?  Is there a better way?
Thanks for anyone helping me on my first post here.

Addition:  Expected output would be:

```
roundCount  invDate     linkField   historyId   itemDesc 
----------------------------------------------------------- 
1           2017-12-01  1           8           something 3   
1           2017-12-01  1           5           toy 2  
1           2017-12-01  1           3           widget 1   
2           2018-01-01  1           9           something 3  
2           2018-01-01  1           5           toy 2   
3           2018-02-01  1           12          prize 4  
3           2018-02-01  1           9           something 3   
3           2018-02-01  1           3           widget 1
```

Comment: What's your expected output for that sample input?

Comment: I noted that as an addition.  thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are actually very very closed. Just need one `OUTER APPLY`

```
-- this is your cteDateTest query
;WITH 
cteDateTest AS 
(
    SELECT 
        1 roundCount
        ,DATEADD(M,DATEDIFF(M,0,@dateFrom),31) invDate --returns first of the month following dateFrom
        UNION ALL
    SELECT
        roundCount + 1
        ,DATEADD(M,1,invDate) --this one would go into the row_number join
    FROM    cteDateTest
    WHERE   DATEADD(M,1,invDate)< @DateTo 
)
SELECT  * 
from    cteDateTest d
    OUTER APPLY
    (
        -- this is your normal query of getting inventory for @dateFrom
        SELECT  SH.historyID
            , I.itemDesc
        FROM    #tempItems I
            INNER JOIN 
            (
                SELECT  ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY itemId ORDER BY statusDate DESC) AS [Index], 
                    itemId, historyID, statusDate, statusIsInInventory
                FROM    #tempStatusHistory 
                WHERE   statusDate < d.invDate  -- change to invDate from cteDateTest
            ) SH    ON  I.id = SH.itemId 
                AND SH.[Index] = 1 
        WHERE   SH.statusIsInInventory = 1
    ) h
```

Comment: Wow, that's GREAT!  Thank you Squirrel.